# CARTO.Geometry field in polygons

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, polygon, data, carto

I want to know how to import a layer of polygons that I have exported from a database in postgis to txt format to my dataset. I have used the ST_GeomFromText function but it does not identify the geometry.

---

I have passed the geometry to geojson from postgis but continuous CARTO is not to identify me as a geometry in the dataset.
An example of the "coordenada" field would be:

{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[443954.068437832,4474249.04503992],[443953.121781595,4474248.30754893],[443952.38433774,4474249.25416733],[443953.330941997,4474249.99165832],[443954.068437832,4474249.04503992]]]]}

I'm importing it from csv as the CARTO example:

name, geojson
"Null Island", "{" "type" ":" "Point" "," "coordinates" ": [0,0]}"

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend converting your layer of polygon to geojson which can reside in a text file or format as you are interested in.

[ST_AsGeoJSON](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html)

> Return the geometry as a GeoJSON element.